# Intall zsh and oh my zsh

Tags: software-installation, zsh

I am trying to install zsh and oh my zsh.

1. `sudo apt install zsh`
2. `chsh -s $(which zsh)`
3. Logout from terminal
4. Reopen terminal

Nothing happens, i expected to see a list of choices, nothing.
Then I enter

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

Response is:

```
Zsh is not installed. Please install zsh first.
```

I don't know what to do?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add the output of the commands `sudo apt install zsh` and `type zsh`. Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code). When installing oh-my-zsh, you are not supposed to issue `chsh` manually, oh-my-zsh will run it _after_ it’s successfully installed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to logout of your system once after step 1 and do step 2 after logging in again to see the installation worked or not.

Comment: Ran into this issue with Ubuntu 20.10. Let me highlight the difference pointed out in this answer from the OP's steps: we often only need to log out of the terminal and then start a new session for changes to take affect. However, with `zsh` on Ubuntu, I had to log my user out of the system, and log back in before the change was complete.